# Calculate Euler equations of fluid dynamics without division?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, computational-physics

I'm working on the calculation of the [Euler equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29) with the [finite volume method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method). Unfortunately I'm not allowed to do a division. So I'm wondering if there's a form which does not need a division.

At the moment the Euler equations look like this:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho \\ \rho v_1 \\ \rho v_2 \\ \rho v_3 \\ \rho E
\end{pmatrix}
= -\mathrm{div}
\begin{pmatrix} \rho v_1 & \rho v_2 & \rho v_3 \\ 
\rho v_1^2 + p & \rho v_1 v_2 & \rho v_1 v_3 \\ 
\rho v_2 v_1 & \rho v_2^2 + p & \rho v_2 v_3 \\ 
\rho v_3 v_1 & \rho v_3 v_2 & \rho v_3^2 + p \\ 
(\rho E + p) v_1 & (\rho E + p) v_2 & (\rho E + p) v_3
\end{pmatrix} $$

As you can see, I first need to calculate $\frac{\rho v_1}{\rho}$ to get $v_1$ so I can calculate e.g. $\rho v_1^2$

Comment: Why can't you do division? I mean, I know that it's more computationally expensive to do division versus multiplication, but I don't understand how you are actually unable to do division.

Comment: Can you do deferred division, it terms of keeping an numerator and denominator separately?

Comment: Well in my design a division costs an additional time step ($z^-1$) and so all the results are wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mean by "division costs an additional time step", could you elaborate?

Comment: @ja72 I've already tried that, without a good result

Comment: I want to do this calculation on the FPGA. I'm using System Generator for that. If you use an division block, you get a delay of one clock.

Comment: Okay, I wouldn't call a clock a "timestep" when dealing with hydrodynamics, as $dt$ is your timestep. I also wouldn't worry about division taking up an extra cycle, you really can't avoid it when using the conservative form (especially if you're using a Riemann solver).

Comment: in this case a clock is a timestep, since I want to calculate each clock the new results. But so I need at least to double the clock, right?

Comment: No, clock is not the same as a timestep. A clock is the inverse of the chip frequency, a timestep is the characteristic time it would take for a fluid parcel to leave the cell (denoted by the Courant-Freidrich-Levy condition).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about numerical methods, not physics.

Comment: @Kyle: [Computational questions are on topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (originated with [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/adding-computational-science-to-the-list-of-on-topic-items-in-the-help-center)).

Comment: @KyleKanos True, though I'd judge this to be very close to the line between computational physics and an implementation issue. Whether it's over the line or not is up for debate.

Comment: How do you plan on dividing by cell volume? Or if you use the primitive system, how will you get $T$ from $e$ without dividing? It's a bit crazy to try and write an entire numerical code without using a single divide.

Comment: @tpg2114: I believe the point is to do as few divides as possible since it takes longer, rather than no divides whatsoever. Though, with Cartesian cells, $dx$ would be constant through the whole sim & could be computed once at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the conservative formalism of the Euler is the primitive form:
$$
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\rho\mathbf v=0 \\
\rho\frac{\partial\mathbf v}{\partial t}+\rho\mathbf v\cdot\nabla\mathbf v+\left(\gamma-1\right)\nabla\left(\rho e\right)=0 \\
\frac{\partial e}{\partial t}+\mathbf v\cdot\nabla e+\left(\gamma-1\right)e\nabla\cdot\mathbf v=0
$$
You shouldn't have to do any division here, as the primitive variables are what are differenced. I haven't really worked with solving a primitive systems, but I don't believe you can use the conventional [Riemann solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_solver), as that expects a conservative system.

Comment: okay, thanks. Do you know a solver for this problem?

Comment: I do not know of any particular solver, but I do not believe you will be guaranteed conservation using the primitive variables (at least to machine precision).

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: When using the primitive form, you are not solving a conservative equation.